# selenium webdriver scripts on phantomcss/ resemblejs or nightmare?

Tags: automated-testing, headless

There are a few headless testing using different tools.

We have created a few IDE scripts in Selenium IDE and successfully ported them over to C# in VS2015.

We want to use some of these Selenium scripts (basically captured clicks on many different web elements in several pages as it helps a lot in regression testing) to do some headless like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) / [nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare) or even possibly using [Resemble.js](https://huddle.github.io/Resemble.js/) to compare images.

What is the best approach?

I was recommended to look into PhantomCSS. Currently, we are testing a combination of legacy products as well as newer apps created in Angular. The selenium scripts had been redone again in VS C# and works very well, but it needs to be headless if possible. The app consists of browsing a site with 100s of pages which displays project/s where the resources are located. When clicked on the icon > the project opens up the location of the project in a map (using google Map API). If possible a screenshot of this project can be captured and compared. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: compare images of important sections of an area on the site for visual difference or changes noted and email the person if possible

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you have described, a feasible (it may not be the best) approach can be:

1. Discuss with the project owner(s) regarding which images of which sections have the highest business value, e.g. worth of testing effort.
2. For each element that is to be tested, produce a object model for it, e.g. what element it is? where it is physically on a page? other attributes of interest and etc.
3. Load your page, read the elements, check for their presences, read their current attributes and compare them against what you have written in your object model.